# Error logging into Bluemix from a GO program

Tags: go, ibm-cloud

I don't know if this is the correct place or not to ask this question.

I am writing a program in GO. I am trying to issue the `bx login` command from the program and it fails. I can manually login on the command line and have the GO program issue the `bx regions` command successfully.

The GO code is:

```
tmpapikey := "--apikey " + risapikey
        cmd := exec.Command("bx", "login", tmpapikey, "-o", "\"Research Integrated Solutions\"", "-s dev")
        cmd.Stdout = &cmdout
        cmd.Stderr = &cmderr
        fmt.Printf("DEBUG: cmd struct is: %+v\n", cmd)
        err = cmd.Run()
        fmt.Printf("DEBUG: stdout from cmd %s, stderr from cmd %s\n",
```

The command in the exec Command structure is:

```
bx login --apikey <Real API key> -o "Research Integrated Solutions" -s dev
```

The error is:

> Incorrect Usage.
>
> NAME:    login - Log user in
>
> USAGE:    bx login [-a API_ENDPOINT] [--sso] [-u USERNAME] [-p
>   PASSWORD] [--apikey KEY | @KEY_FILE] [-c ACCOUNT_ID] [-o ORG] [-s
>   SPACE]

(plus the rest of the help for the `bx login` command).

This exact command will work when run from the command line.

Comment: You probably need to send `"--apikey"` and `risapikey` as separate parameters to `exec.Command()`

Comment: Than you,  Had to break all args up as parm to exec.Command  as cmd := exec.Command("bx", "login", "--apikey", risapikey, "-o", "Research Integrated Solutions", "-s", "dev")